# How to up load xml string to sql server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2010

I have been trying to find the answer to this question for days but can not seem to get it.

I have an xml string obtained from a web service that I need to store in my sql server 2012.

the xml string can be as big as 100k.

I have the following table

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempXML](
[id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
[MyXML] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TempXML] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TempXML] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_TempXML_id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [id]
GO
```

And the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertXML] 
(   @xml xml)

AS  
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
Insert into TempXML
values(NEWID(), @xml)
END
```

When I invoke the sproc if the data size is bigger than 43752 chars its dropping the data and just installing the id.

On the other hand if the field is set to nvarchar(max) the max I can up load before the whole string is dropped is 65535 char's

I am invoking the sproc from c# method

```
internal static void InsertTempMovie(string xml)
{

{
        xmlSouce = xmlSouce.Replace("&", "&amp");
        xmlSouce = xmlSouce.Replace("'", "&apos;");
        xmlSouce = xmlSouce.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>", "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-16\"?>");


        string xmlSouceEncoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xmlSouce);

        LinQTestDataContext dbTempXML = new LinQTestDataContext();
        dbTempXML .ExecuteCommand("exec InsertTempXML @xml={0}",xmlSouceEncoded);
    }
}
```

However I get the same result even if I invoke directly from sql server 2012 management studio

Any ideas as to I can upload the whole string without it being dropped

Thank you in advance

Comment: If your data is `XML` and your parameter is `XML` - why the heck are you storing the data as `Varbinary`?? Makes no sense at all.... XML data is **not** binary data - seems like a really really bad choice of table structure here.....

Comment: Using just basic ADO.NET, I can **easily** insert 450-550K XML documents into a `XML` column in a database table. There's got to be something else that's causing these issues ....

Comment: **HOW** are you accessing the SQL Server database? Are you using Linq-to-SQL, or Entity Framework? Which version?

Comment: Ok my mistake about varbinary I have been trying always to get this thing to work and forgot to change the feild back before scripting it and then posting it good call and my apologies

Comment: As you can see from the code above Im using Linq to access my sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first recommendation would be: since you have XML data and you want to store it - store it as `XML`! Why convert it to `varbinary`? XML is not binary data...

So change your table definition to:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempXML]
(
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [MyXML] [XML] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TempXML] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Next, you can either use just plain ADO.NET to insert those XML files into your database - something like this:

```
// define connection and command in using blocks to ensure proper disposal
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertXML", conn))
{
    cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // define your parameters
    cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml, int.MaxValue);

    // set the parameter values
    string xmlContents = File.ReadAllText(@"...path to your XML file here.....");
    cmdInsert.Parameters["@xml"].Value = xmlContents;

    // open connection, execute command, close connection
    conn.Open();
    int affected = cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
 }
```

Or if you're using Linq-to-SQL, then import the stored procedure you're using into your Linq-to-SQL data context model, and then just call that stored procedure on the `DataContext` class of your model:

```
// use your DataContext class here - in a using block
using (DataClasses1DataContext ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    // load your XML document from a file
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"....path to your XML file here.....");

    // call the stored procedure that's defined on your DataContext class
    ctx.ProcInsertXML(doc.Root);
}
```

Both ways, I was able to insert very large XML (500 KB - 2.5 MB) into SQL Server without any problems whatsoever.

Comment: Its not a file! its a string see my method for calling my sproc above this is not the problem... the limitation of the amount of chars I can upload is...

Comment: Using XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xmlString) I get error 'Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.'

Comment: @user662673: if it's an XML string, then you need to use `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(-your-XML-string-here);` instead; the `Load` method expects a **file name** - not an entire XML string ....

Comment: Sorry I'm being a little silly I corrected my mistake with the XDocument.Parse but still I get the same result... Nothing in the xml column in the database

Comment: Is there a setting in sql server 2012 that I need to set ?

Comment: @user662673: no, I don't think so. As my research has proven to me: SQL Server and C#/ADO.NET/Entity Framework can **easily** handle even much larger XML files. There must be something else getting in your way here.... your question isn't very clear on **how** you get that XML data...... maybe that's the real problem which truncates your data before you can even insert it...

Comment: I am getting my xml from an api from http://www.themoviedb.org/ it is very reliable as I can easily upload everything with less chars than 43752. I can easily send the xml to you or I can set up an ftp.. I don't think this forum allows file upload

Comment: @MrBronz: how are you getting that XML? And you keep talking about *uploading* - where to? What technology is in play here?

Comment: OK uploaded it to your Documents folder.... but dont forget this is in string not file. I mean Upload it to sql server 2012. from my web aplication

Comment: I just noted that the way I was checking for the xml column was populating was visually looking at the column from the initial select top 200 from the sub menue on the table. However this shows NOTHING. but if i do a select xml from my table is shows a link to the data... Yay... It would have been nice if this Usless MS feature would have been announced by MS OK thanks to all looks like its sorted thanks to all but a special thank you to marc_s